# Unable to convert string in to numeric using logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to extract a pattern (line: 85) from the following line using logstash and get the number in a variable as a float value.

```
[JaCoCo plugin] Overall coverage: class: 36, method: 65, line: 85, branch: 76, instruction: 81
```

The logstash filter is as below:

```
filter {
      grok {
        match => ["message", "(?<TotalUnitTCCoveragePercent>line: \d+)"]
       }
     mutate {
        gsub => [
           "TotalUnitTCCoveragePercent", "line: ", ""
               ]
        convert => {
           "TotalUnitTCCoveragePercent" => "float"
          }
      }
 }
```

I am able to extract string "line: 85" and then the value as a string .
However the conversion part it `enter code here`not working.
After executing the pipeline I get "TotalUnitTCCoveragePercent" => 0 and not the float value. Am I missing any thing?
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [mutate filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html), the convert step is done before the gsub step, so the convert step is done on `line: 85` and fails.

The simplest solution is to avoid using the gsub step by using this grok pattern: `line: %{NUMBER:TotalUnitTCCoveragePercent}`. You'll have `85` in `TotalUnitTCCoveragePercent`, so the gsub step will be unnecessary.